# Print icon in the careers page prevents correct mobile page layout from rendering

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

The print icon is preventing the page from loading correctly on mobile.

The icon has a 770px left padding, which seems to be causing the issue.

```
.cv.public a.print {
  left: 770px;
}
```

[image: Print icon]

Comment: As if real, physical printers weren't enough of a problem, now even the iconographic printers are out to haunt us. This never ends.

Comment: There's a print icon on a mobile webpage ? I wonder if that's actually useful..

Comment: @JonasCz Well, it's definitely possible to print from mobile devices. These days though I print web pages from mobile about as much as I print them from desktop. Which is to say, I don't do it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, going out to prod in the next push!